# In Unity, how can I duplicate a GameObject by value so that I can modify it BEFORE instantiating it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a city builder, and I'm writing the part of the game that creates a transparent render of the building you're going to place before you actually place it. What I'd like to do is simply make a copy of the GameObject in code, modify the materials' transparency, remove some components, and then instantiate it.

There's a problem: pretty much everything in Unity is pass by reference. Is there a way to do what I want to do or is there no such way?

Comment: Add a bool like `isPreBuildState` to your prefab. If this is false, object will be tranparent. After build is complete, change the bool to true. If bool is true. Building will be opaque

Answer (score 4):

If you want to create a scene by combining several GameObjects instantiated on runtime, you can create a script called generateEnviroment.cs (just an example name), then you should pass one or several GameObjects as attributes to that script from the inspector.

Next step is to instantiate the correct gameObject and then modify its properties as you please (position, size, material...). Each instance will be independet, with its own attributes that you can modify as you want,and other instances of the same GameObject will not be altered.

```
public GameObject customGameObject1;
public GameObject customGameObject2;

void Start()
{
    generateEnviroment()
}


void generateEnviroment()
{
    //In case you want to add other type of GameObject, like a car or sth you have created:
    GameObject myInstantiatedGameObject = GameObject.Instantiate (customGameObject1);

    //You change its position
    myInstantiatedGameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0.5F, 0);

    // Widen the object by 0.1
    myInstantiatedGameObject.transform.localScale += new Vector3(0.1F, 0, 0);

    //Change material properties, assuming it has a material component
    Renderer rend = myInstantiatedGameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>();
    rend.material.shader = Shader.Find("Specular");
    rend.material.SetColor("_SpecColor", Color.red);
    ...

}
```

You can even add to the GameObject a script component, and you will also be able to access and modify each attribute (variable) in that script independently for each instance of the GameObject (As long as you don't declare that attribute as static)

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to create a copy of your gameobject. Just instantiate it and change values to it's temporary placement state. Like setting material properties, disabling child objects, etc. when the building is finally placed just reset the changes.

Comment: Instantiation *is* creating a copy.

Answer (score 1):

As everyone here already said, creating a copy of prefab or scene object is possible with `GameObject.Instantiate`. You cannot delay *instanitiation* of object (placing it on scene), but you can delay its startup calls (e.g. `Start` and `Awake`). You simply must copy an object that is not active, modify whatever you want and then activate it manually. Is that what you are looking for?

```
static GameObject InstanitateDelay(GameObject source)
{
    bool isActive = source.activeSelf;
    source.SetActive(false); // disable it temporarly
    var go = Instantiate(source); // create inactive copy
    source.SetActive(isActive); // return to previous state
    return go;  // remeber to activate manually via go.SetActive(true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instantiating is the way u duplicate an object in Unity.

If instantiating is to slow for you, just instantiate every object you need, when the scene loads and disable/enable them when you need them.

That way you can change Property before enabling and/or moving it to its final position.

The following call should make it transparent.

```
instantiatedObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = new Color(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

Have look at the following 3 links:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InstantiatingPrefabs.html

https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/instantiate

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.html

Comment: That's not what I'm trying to accomplish. All I'm trying to do is make it so that I have a gameobject that's a copy of another gameobject, BUT the materials are transparent, AND so that I'm not using two prefabs. That's it, it has nothing to do with the speed of instantiation or whatever.